# split a string by key word and return a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string and I want to split it by keyword "When compared to" and return a dictionary for the two parts

These two parts are returned as a dictionary with "diagnostic" and "comparison" as keys. If no "When compared to" is present in the sentence, the value for "comparison" is assigned "NO COMPARISON MADE"

for example

if the string is "this is When compared to which is"

the Output should be:

**diagnostic: this is** (the part before "When compared to")

**comparison: which is** (the part following "When compared to")

if the string is "what a good one"

the Output should be:

**diagnostic: what a good one**

**comparison: NO COMPARISION MADE**

I write the following code but it does not work

```
recomp = re.compile("When compared with")

def identifyComparison(report,recomp):
dict1={}
match = recomp.search(report)

for match in recomp.finditer(report):
    dict1['diagnostic']= report[0:recomp]
    dict1['comparison']= report[recomp:]
    return dict1
else:
    dict1['diagnostic']= report[0:recomp]
    dict1['comparison']= 'no comparison made'
    return dict1
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you have an answer, if that solves your needs accept it. Otherwise comment on what it does, and what you need? Btw, it does look like exactly what you need here. :) cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> my_string= raw_input("Enter a string: ")
Enter a string: this is when compared to which is
>>> result={}
>>> result_list = my_string.split("when compared to")
>>> if(len(result_list)==2):
...     result['dignostic']=result_list[0]
...     result['comparison']=result_list[1]
... 
... else:
...     result['dignostic']=result_list[0]
...     result['comparison']='no comparison made'

>>> result
{'dignostic': 'this is ', 'comparison': ' which is'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data, keys = "this is When compared to which is", ["diagnostic", "comparison"]
print dict(zip(keys, data.split("When compared to") + ['no comparison made']))
# {'comparison': ' which is', 'diagnostic': 'this is '}
```